# codeigniter&soap-JSON data from server could not be parsed

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, soap

Currently I am using in DataTables on server-side in a project. Codeigniter as frame and SOAP as web service.

When I try to run the client-side, a warning was pop out:

> JSON data from server could not be parsed

I made my datatable by follow this [link](https://github.com/blake-nouribekian/codeigniter-datatables/blob/master/data.php).

Here is my server code:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();


      $aColumns = array('time', 'ip_address', 'player_item','comp_item','result');

        // DB table to use
        $sTable = 'rps';
        //

        $iDisplayStart = $CI->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
        $iDisplayLength = $CI->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
        $iSortCol_0 = $CI->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
        $iSortingCols = $CI->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
        $sSearch = $CI->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
        $sEcho = $CI->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

        // Paging
        if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
        {
            $CI->db->limit($CI->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $CI->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
        }

        // Ordering
        if(isset($iSortCol_0))
        {
            for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++)
            {
                $iSortCol = $CI->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
                $bSortable = $CI->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
                $sSortDir = $CI->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

                if($bSortable == 'true')
                {
                    $CI->db->order_by($aColumns[intval($CI->db->escape_str($iSortCol))], $CI->db->escape_str($sSortDir));
                }
            }
        }

        /* 
         * Filtering
         * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
         * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
         * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
         */
        if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch))
        {
            for($i=0; $i<count($aColumns); $i++)
            {
                $bSearchable = $CI->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

                // Individual column filtering
                if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
                {
                    $CI->db->or_like($aColumns[$i], $CI->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                }
            }
        }

        // Select Data
        $CI->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);
        $rResult = $CI->db->get($sTable);

        // Data set length after filtering
        $CI->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
        $iFilteredTotal = $CI->db->get()->row()->found_rows;

        // Total data set length
        $iTotal = $CI->db->count_all($sTable);

        // Output
        $output = array(
            'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
            'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
            'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
            'aaData' => array()
        );

        foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
        {
            $row = array();

            foreach($aColumns as $col)
            {
                $row[] = $aRow[$col];
            }

            $output['aaData'] = $row;
        }

      return json_encode($output);
```

This is the result:

```
JSON:{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":22,"iTotalDisplayRecords":"22","aaData":[]}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to sift though. Have you been able to localize it down to fewer lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your looping `$rResult->result_array()`, you always make new array, and the recent `$row` array will be replace with new `$aRow` array. so place your initialization in outside loop statement.

```
$row = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow){
    foreach($aColumns as $col){
        $row[$i][$col] = $aRow[$col];
    }
    $i++;
}
$output['aaData'] = $row;
```